# Why are Laravel Models static and should I use static functions in my own Models?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel Models use functions that are static and the documentation uses static functions to show how Models work. If I create a new Model for my application, it extends the base Model class but why is Laravel using static functions? I thought the idea is static anything is bad? For example, it makes testing harder?

I'm just confused as most things can be retrieved from the DI container? For example, a Model called Flight, why is it not used like this inside a controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Flight;

class FlightController
{
    public __construct(Flight $flight)
    {
        $this->flight = $flight; // etc.
    }
}
```

And Models are not even using a Facade either? When I create my own models am I suppose to always use static functions as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I think you are mistaking Facades for static methods. Read this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/facades#how-facades-work, Laravel uses the magic method `_callStatic()` to resolve to actual instances. So it looks static, but it isn't.